# Understand hiding process in android

Tags: android, locking

There is someting i'm not guessing. How does photo lock apps work. In which directory do they move the photos so that they are no longer available in the gallery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do that. I think the simplest solution is to make the image not recognizable for the system, in that way the gallery app won't be able to find it. Simple encryption algorithm should do it.